# Vertically center a triangle shape (CSS border hack)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use this CSS border hack to create triangle shapes. They work, but I can't get them vertically centered in their container.

I would use the black triangle entity but it looks different in every font and browser and has weird line height AND isn't vertically centred either. (Why do they even bother making these characters if you can't use them?)

Anyway you can see the [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPBBgM).

Arrows CSS:

```
.ico_arrow_left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-right: 0.75em solid #CCC;
}
.ico_arrow_right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-left: 0.75em solid #CCC;
}
```

Other notes: I'd prefer not to affect the height of any of the containers. Only evergreen browsers needed.

Comment: where you are trying to align

Comment: Within the black box - the triangles should look vertically aligned with the title text. But they drop below the center point of the box and the character descenders. I should have noted that I also don't want to affect the height of any of the containers if possible.

Comment: Instead of using the CSS funkiness you're describing here, you could just use SVG's.  They'll scale forever and you can treat them almost the same as rasterized images.  Might simplify your site a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises due the `line-height` you have set. However I've edited your codepen and here is the new one, also I've not deleted your original `line-height` you have set.
With the increase in line-height, the .btn elements also inherited the line-height and were not aligned properly in the middle. I have added a few changes to your codepen which I have made clear by commenting on the line.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwBqyp

Comment: Thank you, that works quite well! I tried removing my line-height:1.3em, but it looks like those other line-height:100% are still necessary.

Comment: Ahh, one problem I notice is that the button text baseline is a bit lower than the other text now. Bloody CSS.

Comment: All right, after a bit more fiddling I think I got it. I had to apply some of those styles to the bar_title class. [Here's the Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJBXNb)